# VS Code key binding to launch a specific terminal profile

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm on a Windows system and I'm using the following custom key binding to open the default terminal (PowerShell) in the location of the active file:

```
    {
        "key": "alt+t",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.newWithCwd",
        "args": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        }
    }
```

This worked well for my needs but recently I started using Ruby which is installed on WSL, so when I launch the terminal, I get a PowerShell session with no access to the ruby interpreter or irb.

How can I create another key binding that will open a WSL terminal, not the default terminal, in the current working directory?

I tried to bind a key to a couple of commands, the first is to change the default profile and the second is the launch the terminal at the location like so

```
   {
        "command": "runCommands",
        "key": "ctrl+alt+t", 
        "args": {
            "commands": [
                "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "wsl",
                {
                    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.newWithCwd",
                    "args": {
                        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

but VS Code is complaininig about the comma in this line
`"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "wsl"` so I guess the syntax is off

An even better solution would be to keep the current binding but open a different terminal profile based on the file type. e.g. a *.py file will launch a PowerShell terminal and a *.rb file will launch a WSL shell.

Comment: @TimothyG. what does that have to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a command that you can pass both a starting cwd and a terminal profile to, I think you're out of luck- at least at the time of this writing, where the latest stable version of VS Code is 1.82.2.

`terminalStrings.newWithCwd` only takes a cwd: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.82.2/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/terminalActions.ts#L951

`workbench.action.terminal.newWithProfile` only takes a profile: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.82.2/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/terminalActions.ts#L1666

If you're fine with not being able to pass a starting cwd, then just use:

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.newWithProfile",
    "args": {
        "profileName": "", // TODO (you can trigger suggestions for profile names here)
    }
}
```

If you want a command that supports both, you'll probably have to raise a feature-request issue ticket or a Pull Request.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket or writing a PR like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I ended up doing:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+shift+t",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "workbench.action.terminal.newWithProfile",
                "args": {
                    "profileName": "Command Prompt"
                }
            },
            {
                "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
                "args": {
                    "text": "cd ${fileDirname}\n"
                }
            },
            "workbench.action.terminal.focus"
        ]
    }
}
```